# How to grab the value of an xml node - onix file

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmlnode, onix

I'm trying to grab the value of Text in vb, only when TextTypeCode = "02" - if I should change tes to be

```
 tes = (product.Elements(HandleTagName("OtherText"))).value
```

it grabs the entire information including TextTypeCode, TextFormat and Text PublicationDate
but, when

```
  tes = (product.Elements(HandleTagName("Text"))).value
```

it grabs nothing !

```
 For Each ThisOtherText In product.Elements(HandleTagName("OtherText"))
     If ThisOtherText.Element(HandleTagName("TextTypeCode")) = "02" Then
     Dim tes as string = (product.Elements(HandleTagName("Text"))).value
     ThisBook.shortDescription = tes
 Next

<Product>
  <OtherText>
    <TextTypeCode>02</TextTypeCode>
    <TextFormat>05</TextFormat>
    <Text>In a series of humorous incidents and hair-raising episodes </Text>
    <TextPublicationDate>20140422</TextPublicationDate>
  </OtherText>
 </Product>
```

Also I declared shortDescription on the Database as LONGTEXT

Answer (score 0):

node named Text is not direct child of Product, to get to Text you have to go Product.OtherText.Text, the reason you got all values from your first query was due to Product.OtherText grabbing all its children including Text node